# Export an installed package in R

Tags: r, package

Packages come and go,most of the time for good reasons, but sometimes one wants to keep a package that has been discontinued or deleted. Is it then possible to export it from the library to a zip-file etc. that can be installed to another R installation?

Comment: About which OS are you speaking?

Comment: Discontinued packages are always available in the CRAN archive. See `devtools::install_version` for one easy way to get them

Comment: To problematize it @hadley: we don't always get our packages from CRAN or another "stable" source.

Comment: @Pascal: OS  = Windows